# Remove characters from a file name using R

Tags: r

I have several files in a folder. I want to rename some files which starts with character 'NO_' and replace the filename with rest of the characters of the filename. For example: files in folder are: 'NO_123.txt', 'NO_234.txt'.

My desired output filenames are: '123.txt', '234.txt' sequentially.

I am trying something similar as following but couldn't get what should I put in paste0():

```
folder = "~/Desktop/files/"
files <- list.files(folder,pattern = "NO_*.txt",full.names = T) 
sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
  file.rename(from=eachPath,to= sub(pattern="NO_", paste0(""),eachPath))
})
```

Any help for making this code workable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are using in `list.files()` isn't right. This should do:

```
list.files(folder, pattern = "NO_.*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Silly mistake of mine!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, full code with desired outcome can be:

```
path <- r'{E:\temp\test}' ## input path or 'E:/temp/test', This can be any path
files <- list.files(path, pattern = 'NO_\\d+\\.txt') ## regex to search
newname <- sub('NO_','', files) ## new name
file.rename(file.path(path,files), file.path(path, newname)) ## renaming it.
```